# Easiest way of removing # from a certain line in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I remove this line using scripts in bash

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Comment: Do you want to do what your title says or what your questions asks?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from the question header, you need to uncomment the network setting - then the replacing action would be, with a backup:

```
sed -E -i.bak 's/^#(net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1)/\1/g' your-filename
```

The flag *-E* is used to enable the back-reference feature without masking the parentheses, thanks to [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) for clarification in a comment below.

Also, the dots might be masked, but not necessary in this example thought - assuming it is being applied on a */etc/sysctl.conf* and without using flag *-E* and mode *g* it will be:

```
$ sudo sed -i.bak 's/^#\(net\.ipv4\.ip_forward = 1\)/\1/' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Numbered back-references are enabled regardless of the regex option. The only thing `-E` does for you above is allow you to avoid escaping.`'('` and `')'` used for the capture. The `'g'` (global) repeat is not needed (that said, good job - 100% correct approach to remove the existing `'#'`)

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | grep -v "^#net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/^#net\.ipv4\.ip_forward = 1/d' file
```